# `cat ../test` does not find a file. How to force `cat` to not resolve symlink?

Tags: bash, path, symlink

I create this file as:

```
$ echo "ABC" > /home/kes/test
```

I can `cd` to home and out of it:

```
kes@work ~/s $ cd ..
kes@work ~ $ cat test
ABC
kes@work ~ $ cd s
kes@work ~/s $
```

`~/s` is soft link:

```
kes@work ~/s $ pwd
/home/kes/s
kes@work ~/s $ pwd -P
/home/kes/work/projects/safevpn/repo2
```

But when I use relative path it does not work:

```
kes@work ~/s $ cat ../test
cat: ../test: No such file or directory
```

But while

I do not expect that `cat` try to open file in parent directory (resolves symlink) because `cd` does not resolve it:

```
$ rm /home/kes/test
$ mkdir /home/kes/test
$ cd ~/s
$ cd ../test
$ pwd
/home/kes/test
```

How to make these commands work consistent?

Answer (score 3):

If you read the man page of `cd`, you will see that `cd` can or cannot resolve the soft-links, depends on which option do you give (`-L` or `-P`). If no option was given, `cd` uses default `-L`, which means, not resolving soft links.

> If both −L and −P options are specified, the last of these options
>   shall be used
>          and all others ignored. If neither −L nor −P is specified, the operand shall  be
>          handled dot-dot logically;

And

> −L        Handle  the  operand dot-dot logically; symbolic link
>   components shall
>                    not be resolved before dot-dot components are processed (see steps  8.
>                    and 9. in the DESCRIPTION).

Comment: Ok. I like `-L` default option of `cd` command. But how about `cat ../test` to not resolve path? or `<any_command> ../test`?

Comment: @EugenKonkov you can `cat $(pwd)/../test` however I think you can use full path of your file (test)

Comment: This is not inspiring... to check every `..` in path. The symlink also can be in the middle: `cat path/symlink/../test`. This can be meet when path is concatenation result of some configuration options

Comment: @EugenKonkov you see that `cat` doesn't support an option to do like `-L` with `cd`. so you have to diy if you really need it. at least it answered your question: `How to make these commands work consistent?` , you can add `-P` to `cd`, then it works same as `cat`.  Regarding how to implement to fit your requirement better, we have to know the detailed requirement, otherwise, it is hard to provide good solutions.